# What can cause a form to lose its link to its parent form in an MDI vb.net project?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi

Very periodically, some of our forms in our MDI vb.net project will return me.parent as nothing.  I've never seen this while debugging, but it does cause an un-handled exception on our client machines - and the form that they have open varies from case to case.

Is there any sort of event, short of a 'me.parent = nothing', that can cause this link to be broken?

Comment: Any idea as to when does that occur? Any user action? Is it re-producible?

Comment: I cant seem to reproduce this at all.  The users that see this report that they've been doing nothing out-of-the-ordinary when it happens.

The errors seems to occur on a bit of code when a new child form is created, and added to the current forms parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freakin' users.

It looks like this is replicated by closing the current form before the new form can be opened. (In my case, while a report is generating)  The little hour-glass icon wasn't apparently deterrent enough.